# Change element with chosen 2 and name

Tags: python

```
#Question 1
heroes = ["Batman","Wonder Woman","Superman","Spiderman"]
#Question 2
print("Current pilot: ",heroes[0])
#Question 3
print("Co pilot: ",heroes[1])
#Question 4
heroes[2] = "Hit girl"
print(heroes)
['Batman', 'Wonder Woman', 'Hit girl', 'Spiderman']
#Question 5
heroes.append("Cat Woman")
heroes.append("The Flash")
print(heroes)
['Batman', 'Wonder Woman', 'Hit girl', 'Spiderman', 'Cat Woman', 'The Flash']

#Extension
number = input ("What number do you want to replace from 0-5?: ")
If number == 0:
name = input ("With what name do you want to replace number " + number +"?: ")
```

How do you update one of the elements in this list according to the number they chose, and to the
name they chose. So for example, if they chose 2, and Iron Man, how do I change element 2(Hit girl)
to their chosen name(Iron Man)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You do it the same as you did before, except with variables. Did you try anything?

Comment: It seems you want somebody do your homework. Have you tried something?

Comment: sourcerer, yes of course I did, I tried searching the internet as well but didn't find what what I was looking for that's why I ended up asking here. Maybe next time I won't bother asking or please don't reply to me if I'm forced to ask again. Thanks again for your criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heroes = ["Batman","Wonder Woman","Superman","Spiderman"]

print("Current pilot: ",heroes[0])
print("Co pilot: ",heroes[1])

heroes[2] = "Hit girl"

heroes.append("Cat Woman")
heroes.append("The Flash")

print (heroes)

number = input ("What number do you want to replace from 0-5?: ")
name = input ("With what name do you want to replace number " + number +"?: ")

heroes[int(number)] = name

print (heroes)
```

You were right by asking a `number`. Then you ask a `name` to replace the value at the index of your list heroes by that `name`. Then you just replace by doing `heroes[int(number)] = name`

Note that you need `int()` because the number you input is a string, it has to be an integer to be used as index number.

Comment: No problem. Think about accepting the answer if that helped (click on the gray tick top left of my answer, which will turn green!)

Comment: if the answer solved your prooblem, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)